# Interstitial реклама

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, прошу помочь с кодом, решил добавить впервые межстраничный баннер в приложение, но не знаю как сделать заполнение его например через несколько кликов, можете какой нибудь пример показать, чтобы было отчего плясать дальше, а то торможу что то.

```
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getContext(), "");
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
        // Interstitial displayed callback
    }
    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
        // Interstitial dismissed callback
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
    interstitialAd.show();    
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
        // Ad clicked callback
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
        // Ad impression logged callback
    }
});
interstitialAd.loadAd();
```

Comment: Покажите, что сделали и в чём конкретно проблема.

Comment: Вот код, стандартный, не пойму как сделать, чтобы интерститиал через например 5 кликов срабатывал, может покажите какой пример простой.